# Setter not called for Kotlin POJO

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin

I have written a simple POJO (or POKO) and want to use it for data binding inside an Android application written in Kotlin. My problem, the code inside the setter is not called. I expected to see `Set value to <>` in Console. Any idea why this is not happening?

This is the code I posted in [try.kotlinlang.org](https://try.kotlinlang.org):

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var myData = MyData()
    println(myData.helloWorldText)
    println(myData.helloWorldText)
    println(myData.helloWorldText)
    println(myData.helloWorldText)
}

class MyData {

    private val values = listOf<String>("Oh...", "Oh captain...", "Oh captain, my ...", "Oh captain, my captain...")

    private var i = -1

    var helloWorldText: String = ""
        get() = values[++i % values.size]
        set(value) {
            println("Set value to " + field)
        }
}
```

*Background information:* Later on I want make my POJO implement `android.databinding.Observable` and call `registry.notifyChange(this, BR.helloWorldText)` inside the setter.

Comment: Can you post, how you change the value?

Comment: The value can only be changed using the setter. In my app the value is implicitely changed whenever the getter is called. This is working fine so far. The value changes.

Comment: So whats the problem then?

Comment: The code inside the setter is not executed. Hence for data binding I cannot register my `Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback`. [This](https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-observability-9de4ff3fe038) explains how to set a PropertyChangedCallback for Java.

Comment: wait, you set the value for `helloWorldText` but yet the code in setter is not executed?

Comment: @pskink Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I doubt that. So please provide the problematic code, where you set the value and the code is not executed.

Comment: If we could see the setter code indeed. This runs as expected (that is, the "Set value to" line prints as expected when the setter is called) - you can try it yourself at try.kotlin.org.

Comment: I tried [try.kotlinlang.org](https://try.kotlinlang.org). `Set value to` is not shown in console. I will update the question and post the code that I exactly have executed there.

Comment: Your updated code should not show that string, because there is no assignment. So the value is never set.

Comment: So catch the reputation, this answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The code never called the setter, only the getter.

Thank you for the comments that helped to solve the issue. This code is running as expected:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var myData = MyData()
    println(myData.helloWorldText)

    myData.nextValuePlease()        
    println(myData.helloWorldText)
}

class MyData {

    private val values = listOf<String>("Oh...", "Oh captain...", "Oh captain, my ...", "Oh captain, my captain...")

    private var i = 0

    fun nextValuePlease() {
        i = ++i % values.size
        helloWorldText = helloWorldText
    }

    var helloWorldText: String
        get() = values[i]
        set(value) {
            println("Set value to \"" + value+"\"")
        }
}
```